# How to create Neo4J graphs with Spring Roo?

Tags: graph, neo4j, spring-roo, spring-data-neo4j

Is the`graph`package still available in Roo? I would like to create graphs with Neo4J but i can't find any recent documentation or examples about the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, the graph package Neo4j is *not* available in the current, 1.2.5, release of Roo and history informs us that any promise to restore support should be viewed skeptically**

This [antiquated exchange](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/102809-roo-neo4j-status) suggests, along with 3-4 others dated as recently as one year ago, that there is little ground for hope. Moreover, the GitHub activity charts (Sorry, my SO "reputation" is not adequate to post another link. You'll have to figure this one out without help.) show zero development activity related to Spring Roo during the last month. I didn't dig much deeper but the front page shows essentially *no activity in the last six months*. That's *not* a good sign. I did read that [a new development partner has just signed on](http://www.disid.com/web/guest/spring-roo), so maybe things will improve. I'm very new to Roo but I'm finding bug after bug, and problem after problem, many of them outstanding, like the absence of Neo4j, for *years*. I *really* like Roo's ideas and design but I'm not sure that I'm willing to bet on its robustness let alone its longevity. I don't seem to be alone. I searched the web and asked here but can't find *direct* evidence (that is, code that I can examine) that it's being used on real-world projects. Folks pick it up and toy around with it. But if they write more than 40 lines or so of code they don't open their source. (Please understand that I'm no deliberate detractor; I'd be *delighted* to be proven wrong on this point!)

One of the saddest consequences of not having Neo4j is that one of the three existing Roo books, *Getting Started with Roo*, takes it on the chin beginning near the end of the first chapter. This is otherwise an outstanding book. But the absence of Neo4j kicks its ongoing-project model right upside the head. I know the labor entailed by writing a book. Josh Long must be severely disappointed.

More generally, it seems that tech authors are being implicitly encouraged to write small chunks of code that stand on their own, so that their book won't be damaged overall by one or two technological changes. Of course, readers then never get to see code of significant size. I don't have a solution to offer but I'm definitely feeling the problem.

Edited: Because at least one passerby is demonstrably incapable of understanding the implications of *repeatedly broken promises* to *restore* support for Neo4j "in the next few days" *several years ago* I have explicitly spelled out the fact that support is not currently available and no credible promise of soon restoration is to be found. Please note that a *broken* promise to restore support implies that support was *not* restored and subsequent promises to restore support should be treated with some degree of skepticism. So, those who suppose that this answer is "not useful" would likely benefit from the web site. readingcomprehensionconnection.com. Or perhaps the problem is one of attention deficit, which makes it difficult to read more than a few phrases before forming a necessarily hasty conclusion. In that case, one might consider cutting back on the comic books in favor of some reading material without speech balloons. I suppose that I am not alone in finding it difficult to incorporate speech balloons in my merely textual SO comments. Perhaps a future release of SO will support a communication style more familiar and therefore more to one's liking.

---

### Demonstration that Neo4j Is Currently Absent from the Upcoming Release, 1.2.6

The method of search follows the instructions given in (Long & Mayzak, 2011), apparently by Michael Hunger of Neo Technology, Inc., the company that developed Neo4j.

```
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT [rev 32b413d]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
roo> project --topLevelPackage org.hagiasmon.gswr --projectName gswr
Created ROOT/pom.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES/log4j.properties
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT
Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT/applicationContext.xml
roo> pgp trust -keyId 0x29c2d8fd
You must specify option 'keyId' for this command
roo> pgp trust --keyId 0x29c2d8fd
Added trust for key:
>>>> KEY ID: 0x29C2D8FD <<<<
     More Info: http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?fingerprint=on&op=index&search=0x29C2D8FD
     Created: 2011-Jan-06 10:48:11 +0000
     Fingerprint: 558eb0489fe5500c68fa8a306107f33d29c2d8fd
     Algorithm: RSA_GENERAL
     User ID: Michael Hunger <Michael.Hunger@jexp.de>
          Signed By: Key 0x29C2D8FD (Michael Hunger <Michael.Hunger@jexp.de>)
     Subkey ID: 0xDEFB5FB1 [RSA_GENERAL]

roo> addon search graph
0 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.2 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
roo>
```

P.S. I initiated Facebook correspondence with Josh Long, who along with Michael Hunger, are the two folks driving the Roo - Neo4j interface, as far as I can tell. If he responds, I'll update this comment.